CompletableFuture not working as expected and having more number of extra threads
I'm trying to parallelize the below operation of fetching all the records with 50000 records in each iteration with pagination and writing them into a CSV file on an s3 file.
Before Parallelism:
public void generateStudentFiles(){

  int pageCount =0;
  boolean isEndOfFile=false;
  while(isEndOfFile){
    // step1: fetch the records from the db with pagination
    List<StudentEntity> result = repo.getStudentDataWithPagination(50000,pageCount);
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(result) || result.size() < 50000){
         isEndOfFile = true;
    } else {
      // step2: void method to write records into csv file on s3 location
      writeResultToS3(result);
    }
    pageCount++;

   }

}

After Parallelism:
I want to write the files up to a maximum of 5 threads concurrently.
public void generateStudentFiles(){
     
      // created 5 threads for concurrency or parallelis 
      ForkJoinPool customPool = new ForkJoinPool(5);    
      CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

      int pageCount =0;
      boolean isEndOfFile=false;
      while(isEndOfFile){

      CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
          
        // step1: fetch the records from the db with pagination
        List<StudentEntity> result = repo.getStudentDataWithPagination(50000,pageCount);
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(result) || result.size() < 50000){
             isEndOfFile = true;
        } else {
          // step2: void method to write records into csv file on s3 location
          writeResultToS3(result);
        }
        pageCount++;          

      }, customPool);
        
    
       }

future.complete(null);
    
}

Expected output of the above parallelism code:
The whole operation of fetching the records from the Database and writing on the s3 location should be running parallelly on 5 threads and reduce the time taken for writing the file
Actual output of the above parallelism code:
There were more than 5 threads(not sure why there are extra threads) running randomly and generating many empty CSV files on the s3 location. for example, instead of seeing 50 files, there were 200 files where 150 files were blank and 50 files had data and thread execution was never getting ended. Any suggestion please on how to resolve this issue?

You are making things overly complex. Just create a threadpool with 5 threads and schedule the tasks. If you are using Spring just use an AsyncTaskScheduler. It is also a fallicy to think that adding more threads will speed things up. Reading is still limited as well as writing CSV files, if you are writing to 1 file it will not even work. Finally your if is wrong and the last segment will never be written.

Do you have a specific reason to write CollectionUtils.isEmpty(result) instead of a straight-forward result.isEmpty()? Are you sure that you want to treat the result.size() < 50000 condition the same as an empty list, in other words, not write those up to 50000 elements to S3? Besides that, the second code does not even pass the compiler. So it can’t produce the result you claim.

To improve your performance instead of throwing threads at the problem first analyze where the problem lies. I would start by increasing the JDBC fetch size (default is 10) to something like a 1000 this will decrease the roundtrips to the database. I'm not sure how you are writing the CSV file(s) but instead of retrieving with JPA and mapping that to CSV, retrieve what you need to directly write the CSV (and don't use objects to navigate).

I have found a few problems in your code, however, I have corrected and tested  the code. It's working parallely now.
public static void  generateStudentFiles(){
    // created 3 threads for concurrency or parallelis
    ExecutorService customPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    int pageCount =0;
    boolean isEndOfFile=true;
    while(isEndOfFile){

        List< StudentEntity> result = getStudentDataWithPagination(50000,pageCount);
        result.stream().map(str -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->writeResultToS3(str),customPool)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        pageCount = pageCount++ // you need to check this logic for updating PageCount;

        if(pageCount==50000) // your need to check this logic for breaking the loop 
            isEndOfFile=false;
    }
}  

Please try this. It should work for you.

Here, writeResultToS3() is working parallelly with created 3 threads only. Feel free to reach out if any concerns

For getStudentDataWithPagination part- you can write code like below :
List result= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> getStudentDataWithPagination(3,pageCount),customPool).get()

If you want to combine both operations in one line then please check thenApply() ,thenRun() callback methods of CompletableFuture.

Also, for managaement of threads according to DB connections, you might want to check ThreadPoolExecutor.

Can we also make the getstudentdata.. part concurrent just like similarly to writeresultstos3 part?

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

@ArunSaiMustyala getStudentDataWithPagination() method, you can call one more CompletableFuture with supplyAsync(). Once you will get the result then call writeResultToS3().  Please note that threads for first method for method getStudentDataWithPagination() will depends on number of DB connections also.
